# How to set a cookie on jQuery toggle and remember the toggle position?

Tags: jquery, cookies, toggle, slidetoggle

I have a simple example of a toggle menu and I want to use a JavaScript cookie to make it persistent.

I am not sure what the logic should be when using this toggle event.

```
$('.show_menu').on('click', function() {
  $('.top_menu_hidden').stop().slideToggle('normal', function(){
    // some code here
  });
});​
```

A live example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/zR4AV/)

I'm using the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/zR4AV/4/

Answer (score 0):

Setting cookies using javascript is a pretty ugly affair, but here's a good example from w3schools:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp